How do I change folder icons in linux nautilus select file screen?
I'm using Pop os, based on ubuntu, and I like to change my folder icons to make it faster to navigate my branching tree mess of a file structure. I found (quite easily) how to change the folder icon in the "default mode" :

And as you can see, it's working quite well :

But there is another "mode", the "select file mode", that doesn't show my icons (same folder different mode):

Is there a way to make them appear in the latter mode? It is wasting so much of my time, constantly having to read every folder name, just to find the right one, every time I have to select something, I really want to have the icons in that mode too.

The "select file" dialog is not Nautilus and has never been Nautilus. It's the GTK3 file chooser dialog, which is a completely separate program – the only parts it shares with Nautilus are the sidebar and path bar, and even that only via manual copy-paste of code. (Notice how the "select file" dialog's path bar still has the earlier design that Nautilus had 4–5 releases ago...) Everything else is independent, including the file list widget.
As far as I can see, the GTK file chooser just doesn't have code to look up icons from individual folder metadata.
The "select file" dialog will be Nautilus in the future – work is ongoing to replace the GTK built-in dialog with a special Nautilus mode, and the results can be seen in GNOME 47 (at least for apps which use the new "XDG-Portal" framework, such as Google Chrome). But that was only implemented ~4 months ago; neither Pop!OS 22.04 nor 24.04 include those changes yet.

Awww... That's a shame.
